# How to make a PostGIS LINESTRING with only one initial point

Tags: postgresql, geometry, gis, postgis

I have a service that will be sending GPS coordinates as it moves, and these will be added to my PostgreSQL / PostGIS database.

Right now, created a table with one column that is a Geometry("LINESTRING") type. However, it seems that in order to make a LINESTRING, you need at least two points.

But, I will only be receiving one point at a time. So initially when the service starts sending me location data, it only has one location to send. I will have to wait for the second location submission in order to have at least two points. So what should I do when I receive the first point since I can't make a LINESTRING out of it yet?

What is the recommended procedure to follow in this case for the initial case when I only have one point so far?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [`ST_MakeLine`](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_MakeLine.html) to create `LineStrings` you will be able to temporary add your *one-point-line* into a `LineString` geometry column:

Quick&Dirty:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE t (id int, geom Geometry(LINESTRING));  

INSERT INTO t VALUES (1, (SELECT ST_MakeLine('POINT(1 2)'::geometry)));
SELECT id,ST_AsText(geom) FROM t;

 id |    st_astext    
----+-----------------
  1 | LINESTRING(1 2)
(1 Zeile)
```

Then updating it with the same function should also work:

```
UPDATE t SET geom = ST_MakeLine(geom,'POINT(2 3)')
WHERE id = 1;

SELECT id,ST_AsText(geom) FROM t;

 id |      st_astext      
----+---------------------
  1 | LINESTRING(1 2,2 3)
(1 Zeile)
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems odd to have a linestring with a single point.

But what about a degenerate one like

```
'LINESTRING(1.23 4.56,1.23 4.56)'::geometry
```

Comment: Yeah this is the solution I already went with - to just duplicate the initial point. But I thought there might be a standard way of addressing my original problem, so I posted the question, but perhaps not.

Comment: Perhaps it would be better to choose a more appropriate type like a collection of points and construct the linestring from it only when you need it.

Comment: that's a good point. But I guess now that I think about it, what's the point of actually use linestring for me? I just was going to use a linestring since I wanted to have a gps path of points as a person moves. But I could definitely just store that as a collection of points. 
Would the only cases in which I need to turn the collection of points into a linestring be if I wanted to do something like detect when two lines overlap? 
For just displaying the points on a map, I wouldn't need a linestring right?

Comment: (assuming that the collection of points maintain the order in which I insert the points).